# What's the best way to attack a base full of mortars and AA sites?

Tags: warzone-2100

How should I attack a base full of mortars and AA sites?  This means any VTOLs won't be a solution to attacking the base.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried designing fast Long range units (like Mortars) so that you can do hit an run tactics while using VTOL to cover them, that way when the enemy mortars fire back you can pull your strike team back quickly.

ofcause you may still loose some in the retreat since adding Mortars will slow your units down and compensating them with lighter bodies or faster treads/wheels will give them less HP than a probably designed Mortar Platform like unit (using the best body and treds/wheels but making it slow as hell)